# Why do I get warning: braces around scalar initializer?

Tags: c, gcc, warnings

I have this code:

```
typedef char **Runlevel[];
```

```
Runlevel runlevel_default = {
    { "/usr/bin/test", NULL },
};
```

And if I try to compile it, I get warnings like:

- `warning: braces around scalar initializer`
- `warning: initialization of ‘char **’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char *’`
- `warning: excess elements in scalar initializer`

However, when I write it like this:

```
char *args[] = { "/usr/bin/test", NULL };

Runlevel runlevel_default = {
    args
};
```

I don't get any warnings. What's the problem?

**EDIT**: My target is to make an array of runlevels. Like in comment of @Paul Ogilvie, I removed nested brackets, but now when I am making something like this:

```
Runlevel runlevel_default[] = {
    { "/usr/bin/test", NULL }
};
```

I am getting another error: `error: array type has incomplete element type ‘Runlevel’ {aka ‘char **[]’}`

What can be a problem now?

Comment: You nest the `{` brace. One is enough. so: `Runlevel runlevel_default []= { "/usr/bin/test", NULL };`

Comment: I am getting another error: error: array type has incomplete element type `‘Runlevel’ {aka ‘char **[]’}`.
Runlevel is already an array of char** and now you have an array of char** arrays.

What you probably want is that Runlevel is an array of char* and that runlevel_default is of type Runlevel and not Runlevel[].

Comment: `char *[]` and `char**[]` mean different things. If you love strange bugs like this, then keep hiding your pointers behind `typedef`. If you hate bugs, then don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `typedef char **Runlevel[];` statement isn't defining what you appear to want; with that statement, `RunLevel` is *not* a 2-D array of `char*` pointers but a **1-D array** of `char**` elements. Thus, not only does your subsequent initialization of the `runlevel_default` variable have too many sets of braces, but the individual elements (string literals and the `NULL` token) are of the wrong type (they are 'valid' `char*` values but not `char**`).

So, what you maybe looking for is something like `typedef char *Runlevel[][];` – but this is not valid, because only *one* dimension of a multi-dimensional array can have an unspecified size, to be determined by the compiler when such an array type is declared/initialized.

So, assuming each sub-element of your array will be **two** (and *only* two) `char*` pointers (possibly to string literals), then you need to specify that `2` as the last (innermost) dimension:

```c
typedef char* Runlevel[][2];

Runlevel runlevel_default = {
    { "/usr/bin/test", NULL },
    { "/usr/bin/test2", NULL },
    { "/usr/bin/test3", NULL },
};
```

Using this syntax, the value of the 'empty' dimension in the `typedef` will be determined by the compiler according to how many brace-enclosed pairs of `char*` values you include in the (also brace-enclosed) initialization list; in the above code, the `runlevel_default` variable will be as if declared `char* runlevel_default[3][2]`. However, you could also declare a different variable of `Runlevel` type, with a different 'outer' dimension, like so:

```c
Runlevel runlevel_different = {
    { "/usr/bin/test", NULL },
    { "/usr/bin/test2", NULL },
    { "/usr/bin/test3", NULL },
    { "/usr/bin/test4", NULL },
    { "/usr/bin/test5", NULL }, // This time, we have 5 as the outer dimension
};
```

Comment: Or just drop the `typedef` which only fills the purpose of creating bugs and confusion in this case.

Comment: @Lundin - Yeah, one *could* consider this 'abuse' of the `typedef` ... but that's down to the coding style. If you're going to be using the type a lot, there *may* be an argument for `typedef`.